# Resolving InvalidTimestampException with Confluent-Kafka-Go v1.8.x and Kafka v3.2.x: Seeking Clarification on Timestamp and Leader Epoch Issues

Tags: go, apache-kafka, confluent-kafka-go

Understanding and Troubleshooting Timestamp-related Issues in Confluent-Kafka-Go and Kafka Server Integration...

I'd like to ask if anyone has encountered the following issue when using confluent-kafka-go v1.8.x to connect to a Kafka v3.2.x server: A particular topic on the Kafka server logs an INFO message stating "starts at leader epoch", after about half an hour, followed by an InvalidTimestampException error that says "One or more records have been rejected due to invalid timestamp".

like this:

`Removed fetcher for partitions Set({My_Topic}) Stopped fetchers as part of LeaderAndIsr request correlationId 293 from controller 0 epoch 3 as part of the become-leader transition for 1 partitions`

`Loading producer state till offset 0 with message format version 2`

`Created log for partition {My_Topic} in /var/lib/kafka/{My_Topic} with properties {}`

`[Partition {My_Topic} broker=2] No checkpointed highwatermark is found for partition {My_Topic}`

`[Partition {My_Topic} broker=2] Log loaded for partition {My_Topic} with initial high watermark 0`

`Leader {My_Topic} starts at leader epoch 0 from offset 0 with high watermark 0 ISR [2,1,0] addingReplicas [] removingReplicas []. Previous leader epoch was -1.`

And this:

`Error processing append operation on partition {My_Topic} org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidTimestampException: One or more records have been rejected due to invalid timestamp`

This error doesn't occur after upgrading confluent-kafka-go to v2, and I haven't found any commit addressing valid message timestamp issues when comparing the source code before and after the upgrade. There seems to be a parameter related to the timestamp and leader epoch, but the Kafka server's code only reports the aforementioned error when verifying memory record messages. I've been pondering this issue for a while and still don't understand it, so I hope someone can help clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I found the root cause: the high CPU usage at 100% for a long time may be causing a large number of messages with invalid timestamps...

There doesn't seem to be a strong relationship between the version of Kafka and confluent-kafka-go.

The issue is that Kafka only uses log4j, but our server has a custom log4j2.xml file that overwrites some of Kafka's log paths...

```
https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8222942
```